# amsthm with shared counters messes up autoref references

Tags: hyperref, theorems, amsthm

When I define `amsthm` theorem environments with shared counters,
autoref messes up the names of the references.
For example, in the output below, we should have "Definition 2" instead of "Theorem 2".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\label{wonderful-theorem}
This is a wonderful theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
\label{awesome-definition}
This is an awesome definition.
\end{definition}

Look at the wonderful \autoref{wonderful-theorem}
and the awesome \autoref{awesome-definition}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the record: `\theoremstyle{theorem}` is not defined by default (as pointed out by skpblack in a comment to [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187395/)). You probably meant `plain`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would use `cleveref` instead, which does understand `amsthm`.  The following is close to the output you were getting above:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\label{wonderful-theorem}
This is a wonderful theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
\label{awesome-definition}
This is an awesome definition.
\end{definition}

Look at the wonderful \cref{wonderful-theorem}
and the awesome \cref{awesome-definition}.

\end{document}
```

Personally I would not use the `nameinlink` option, and `cleveref` describes it as bad style.  Without this option the hyperlink is just the number and the click area does not include the name.

Note the order of the package loading, cf. [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/15925)

Comment: Note that for this to work, it is important that `\newtheorem` comes **after** including cleveref. This makes it much harder if you are using a documentclass like lipics that already includes hyperref and amsthm and does the newtheorem, but does not include cleveref.

Comment: I am currently using package etoolbox so I can `\undef{\lemma}` and `\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}` after including package cleveref. That's nor very clean... (an alternative is to define and use lemm, which does the same as lemma)

Comment: For `cleveref` to distinguish between different theorem names with a shared counter, it appears to be vital that `\usepackage{amsthm}` is added *before* `\usepackage{cleveref}`.

Comment: @qwertz `cleveref` has to come after most packages, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/15925

Answer (score 17):

This problem isn't so easy to solve. the problem consist in this:

- `hyperref` only defines a name if you use `\newtheorem{theorem}{<theorem name>}` for using with `\autoref`. This name is `Theorem` in English (obviously changes if we use `babel`), it is stored in the macro `\theoremautorefname` and can be changed using `\renewcommand{\theoremautorefname}{<new name>}`.
- If you create a different structure (for example `\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}`) `\autoref` doesn't put any name.
- `\autoref` works via the counter name (in this case `theorem`) where the reference is based on.
- Sometimes `\autoref`chooses the wrong name, if the counter is used for diﬀerent things. For example, it happens with `\newtheorem` if a *lemma* (or other structure created by the user) shares a counter with *theorems*.

For this the package `aliascnt` provides a method to generate a simulated second counter that allows the diﬀerentiation between theorems and lemmas or other structures.

---

To solve this problem i recommend to do this:

- Load the `aliascnt` package with `\usepackage{aliascnt}`.
- Create the main structure (if you plan to share the counters) with

  ```
  \newtheorem{<main str>}{<Main str name>}
  ```

  (This fixes the counter).
- If your structure is not a `theorem` create a new name for `\autoref` using `\providecommand*{\<main str>autorefname}{<Main str name>}`. For example if you want a `lemma` use

  ```
  \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
  \providecommand*{\lemmaautorefname}{Lemma}
  ```
- If you don't plan to share counters simply use

  ```
  \newtheorem{<name>}{<Name>}
  \providecommand*{\<name>autorefname}{<Name>}
  ```

  for each `<name>` theorem.
- If you plan to share counters with `<main str>` then for each `<newTh>` (new theorem) write

  ```
  \newaliascnt{<newTh>}{<main str>}% alias counter "<newTh>"
  \newtheorem{<newTh>}[<newTh>]{<newTh name>}
  \aliascntresetthe{<newTh>}
  \providecommand*{\<newTh>autorefname}{<newTh name>} % name for \autoref
  ```

Here is the code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{aliascnt}

\theoremstyle{theorem}
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{definition}
    \newaliascnt{definition}{theorem}
    \newtheorem{definition}[definition]{Definition}
    \aliascntresetthe{definition}
    \providecommand*{\definitionautorefname}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\label{wonderful-theorem}
This is a wonderful theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
\label{awesome-definition}
This is an awesome definition.
\end{definition}

Look at the wonderful \autoref{wonderful-theorem}
and the awesome \autoref{awesome-definition}.

\end{document}
```

and the result

[image]

Comment: i must clarify that `\theoremstyle{theorem}` is not defined by default (by default is `plain`). you must define it using `\newtheoremstyle...` or to use the `plain` style (by default).

Comment: Maybe using `cleveref` and its `\cref` command would solve the problem?

Answer (score 11):

The package `thmtools` fixes this. From the documentation:

> **A.1.7 Fixing autoref and friends**
>
> `hyperref`’s `\autoref` command does not work well with theorems that share a counter:  it’ll always think it’s a Lemma even if it’s a Remark that shares the Lemma counter. Load this package to fix it. No further intervention
>   needed.

Indeed, merely loading the package fixes the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\label{wonderful-theorem}
This is a wonderful theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
\label{awesome-definition}
This is an awesome definition.
\end{definition}

Look at the wonderful \autoref{wonderful-theorem}
and the awesome \autoref{awesome-definition}.

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if you're going to use `thmtools`, you might as well take advantage of its more concise theorem declarations: replace

```
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
```

by

```
\declaretheorem[style=plain]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[style=definition,sibling=theorem]{definition}
```

(Of course, these are but two of the many features of `thmtools`.)