# \autoref{} printed "Theorem 2.1" instead of "Lemma 2.1". How to change?

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing

I labeled my lemma with \label{lem1} and referred to it later using \autoref{lem1}. However, what was printed was "Theorem 2.1" where it should really say "Lemma 2.1". How do I fix this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{thesis}
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsfonts,amscd,amsrefs}
\newtheoremstyle{component}{}{}{}{}{\itshape}{.}{.5em}{\thmnote{#3}#1}
    \theoremstyle{component}
    \newtheorem*{component}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{lemma} \label{lem1}
This is a lemma.
\end{lemma}

By \autoref{lem1}, we have..

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looking into my chrystal ball of magic it says: Please provide a MWE ;-)

Comment: oh no sorry! New here I keep forgetting. Let me edit it in real quick.

Comment: The Internet is chock-full of documentclass files named either `Thesis.cls` or `thesis.cls`. Where did you obtain your variant from?

Comment: from my senior in school. Here's the one I have: https://app.box.com/s/0zc51evopkdpulxgygqjuadocxyv97tw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not related to the .cls file and is well documented, see e.g. [amsthm with shared counters messes up autoref references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187388/amsthm-with-shared-counters-messes-up-autoref-references)

You could use any of the two solutions proposed in that post, and I would recommend using `cleveref` as in the second one. To do that, just include

```
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

in the .cls file, right after

```
\usepackage{...,amsthm,...}
```

Then use `\Cref{lem1}` (instead of `autoref`) in the document. The code would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemm}[theorem]{Lemma}
\begin{document}

\begin{lemm}\label{lem1}
This is a lemma.
\end{lemm}

By \Cref{lem1}, we have.

\end{document}
```

If you didn't want to modify the .cls file, an easier but less robust solution is to define a newcommand `\lref` for lemmas (and then another command \dref for definitions, etc.) through

```
\newcommand\lref[1]{Lemma~\ref{#1}}
```

I say this is less robust because you can always make a mistake and use `\lref` to quote, let's say, a definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemm}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newcommand\lref[1]{Lemma~\ref{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{lemm}\label{lem1}
This is a lemma.
\end{lemm}

By \lref{lem1}, we have.

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for this and the link to the other article. I tried adding \cleveref to Thesis.cls, but adding that caused \begin{definition}..\end{definition} environment to be unrecognisable by the compiler.

Comment: Do the following in the .cls file: 1) Change `cref` to `chref` in `\newcommand{\cref}[1]{Chapter~\ref{#1}}`. 2) Move `\usepackage{cleveref}` and all the lines from `\theoremstyle{plain}` to `\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}` right after `\usepackage[...]{hyperref}`. This should solve all your problems.