# \autoref does not show the right reference name

Tags: cross-referencing, autoref

In my tex document I have 3 environments for Definition, Theorem and Lemma.

The numbering of them should be continuous as follows:

```
Definition 1.1
Theorem 1.2
Lemma 1.3
Definition 1.4
...
```

I got it by the following:

```
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}[defn]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[defn]{Lemma}

\def\defnautorefname{Def.}
\def\theoremautorefname{Thm.}
\def\lemmaautorefname{Lem.}
```

So far so good. Then I want to make reference to each of them using `\autoref`, for instance:

```
\autoref{defn:1}    
\autoref{theorem:1}    
\autoref{lemma:1}
```

But what I obtain is only:

```
Def. 1.1
Def. 1.2
Def. 1.3
```

and **NOT** as I would like to have:

```
Def. 1.1
Thm. 1.2
Lem. 1.3
```

My full code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}[defn]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[defn]{Lemma}


\def\defnautorefname{Def.}
\def\theoremautorefname{Thm.}
\def\lemmaautorefname{Lem.}


\parindent0pt


\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\begin{defn}
 \label{defn:1}
 Def 1
\end{defn}


\begin{theorem}
 \label{theorem:1}
 Theorem 1
\end{theorem}


\begin{lemma}
 \label{lemma:1}
 Lemma 1
\end{lemma}


\begin{defn}
 \label{defn:2}
 Lemma 1
\end{defn}




Here should be Definition: \autoref{defn:1}

Here should be Theorem: \autoref{theorem:1}

Here should be Lemma: \autoref{lemma:1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The description of `\autoref` in the `hyperref` manual is useful.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I also read it, but I cannot find the way to solve my problem :(

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why aren't you using `cleveref`?

Comment: I don't know about cleveref. Could you please give me an example with cleveref related to my problem? Thank you.

Comment: Just found [amsthm with shared counters messes up autoref references](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187388) by the way.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. : Thank you. The link you gave is greate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cleveref` package provides the `\cref` macro, which is even more clever [pun intended] than `\autoref`. For instance, it can take multiple arguments. In addition, `\cref` is better than `\autoref` at figuring out which label to use when several environments share a common counter, as is the case with `definition`, `theorem`, and `lemma` in your example

In the following example, the `cleveref` package is loaded with the option `nameinlink`. This makes both the label and the number part of the hypertarget, mimicking the look of cross-references generated by `\autoref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%%\usepackage{ucs} % don't use it; it's deprecated
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}[defn]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[defn]{Lemma}

\crefname{defn}{definition}{definitions}
\Crefname{defn}{Definition}{Definitions}


%\def\defnautorefname{Def.}
%\def\theoremautorefname{Thm.}
%\def\lemmaautorefname{Lem.}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\begin{defn} \label{defn:1} Def 1 \end{defn}
\begin{theorem} \label{theorem:1} Theorem 1 \end{theorem}
\begin{lemma} \label{lemma:1} Lemma 1 \end{lemma}
\begin{defn} \label{defn:2} Definition 2 \end{defn}

Here are two Definitions: \Cref{defn:1,defn:2}

Here is a Theorem: \Cref{theorem:1}

Here is a Lemma: \Cref{lemma:1}

\end{document}
```